# ERROR. org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

i am deploying web-site(spring) in tomcat7 but it is giving error-

```html
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'class path resource [jdbc/sqlMapper_board.xml]'; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class . Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'BoardVO'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: BoardVO
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5017)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5531)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried to fix this error many times but I failed. How can I solve this problem?
here is my root-context and sqlMapper.xml

root-context

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

 <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

 <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
   <value>classpath:jdbc/oracle.properties</value>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
  <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
  <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
 </bean>

 <!-- ////////////////////// 타일즈 관련 설정 //////////////////////// -->

 <!-- 설정파일 지정하기 -->
 <bean id="tilesConfig"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
  <property name="definitions">
   <list>
    <value>/WEB-INF/home_tiles.xml</value>
    <value>/WEB-INF/member_tiles.xml</value>
    <value>/WEB-INF/test_tiles.xml</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>
 <!-- 뷰를 타일즈로 지정하기 -->
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="order" value="0" />
  <property name="viewClass"
   value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
  <property name="viewNames" value=".*" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <!-- <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:jdbc/sqlMapper_*.xml" 
   /> -->
  <property name="mapperLocations">
   <list>
    <value>classpath:jdbc/sqlMapper_member.xml</value>
    <value>classpath:jdbc/sqlMapper_board.xml</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
  <constructor-arg ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="MemberService" class="test.com.tilesmember.service.MemberService">
 </bean>

</beans>
```

sqlMapper.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="test.com.tileslayout">

 
 <sql id="where"> 
  <where>
  <if test="searchText != ''">
   <if test="searchType == 'ALL'">
   SUBJECT LIKE CONCAT('%',#{searchText},'%') OR NAME LIKE CONCAT('%',#{searchText},'%') OR CONTENT LIKE CONCAT('%',#{searchText},'%')
   </if>
   <if test="searchType == 'TITLE'">
   SUBJECT LIKE CONCAT('%',#{searchText},'%')
   </if>
   <if test="searchType == 'NAME'">
   WRITER LIKE CONCAT('%',#{searchText},'%')
   </if>
   <if test="searchType == 'CONTENT'">
   CONTENTS LIKE CONCAT('%',#{searchText},'%')
   </if>
  </if> 
  </where>
 </sql>

 <select id="selectList" parameterType="BoardVO" resultType="BoardVO">
  SELECT
   NUM
     ,TITLE
     ,NAME
     ,CONTENT
     ,HIT
     ,REG_DATE as regDate
  FROM
   BOARD
  <include refid="where"/>
  ORDER BY NUM DESC
  LIMIT #{startIndex}, #{listCount}
 </select>
 
 <select id="selectCount" parameterType="BoardVO" resultType="int">
  SELECT COUNT(NUM) FROM BOARD
  <include refid="where"/>
 </select>
 
 <select id="select" parameterType="BoardVO" resultType="test.com.tilesmember.model.BoardVO">
  SELECT
   NUM
     ,TITLE
     ,NAME
     ,CONTENT
     ,HIT
     ,REG_DATE as regDate
  FROM
   BOARD
  WHERE
   NUM = #{num}
 </select>
 
 <insert id="insert" parameterType="test.com.tilesmember.model.BoardVO">
  INSERT INTO BOARD (
   TITLE
     ,NAME
     ,CONTENT
     ,HIT
     ,REG_DATE
  ) VALUES (
   #{title}
     ,#{name}
     ,#{content}
     ,0
     ,NOW()
     ,NOW()
  )
 </insert>
 
 <update id="update">
  UPDATE BOARD SET 
   TITLE  = #{title}
     ,NAME  = #{name}
     ,CONTENT = #{content}
  WHERE
   NUM = #{num}
 </update>

 <update id="updateHit">
  UPDATE BOARD SET HIT = HIT + 1 WHERE NUM = #{num}
 </update>

 <delete id="delete">
  DELETE FROM BOARD WHERE NUM = #{num}
 </delete>

</mapper>
```

Comment: Is test.com.tilesmember.model.BoardVO defined somewhere?

Comment: I made a mistake. BoardVO is located test.com.tilesboard.model.BoardVO.

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Comment: I fixed that. but error is still happend.

Comment: Does it now say test.com.tilesboard.model.BoardVO is missing or something else?

Comment: I guess it is something else. I fixed all test.com.tilesmember.model.BoardVO -> test.com.tilesboard.model.BoardVO. I guess sqlSessionFactory is problem  but I couldn't find a solution yet.